# Page curl animation - issue

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am developing a project in which on the same view when a button clicks, the contents got changed. e.g.

suppose there are 5 questions and on next button click, the questions and answers will change, from 1-5 questions. and I want to implement page curl animation on button click...

I got the page curl animation code from github  https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl , but still confused with how to implement this project as a library in my application,

so that I can use the page curl animation when the user click on next and previous button, can anyone pplss guide me into this, how can I implement this code on next button click...

Thanks.....

Comment: May u please guide me to show the curl animation on click of the button.i want to implement this in my app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had used Page Curl example.. I am posting my code.. I hope it helps you..
On next button click write below code:-

```
PageCurlView pageCurlView = new PageCurlView(this, true);              
// If you would like to see the on-screen debug info
pageCurlView.bDrawDebug = true;
this.setContentView(pageCurlView);
```

You can get PageCurlView.java. from [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/j0bUAdu2/PageCurlView.html).

You can set color of "mCurlEdgePaint". And put your background in this lines

```
mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.background_main);
mForeground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.background_main_bg);
```

Comment: Ok Kanika.. You are most welcome.. It would be nice if you are accept this answer as a answer if it is really helps you then.

Comment: @mpp i want to use this page curl in my app.Please help me. My question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779862/how-can-i-show-page-on-full-screen-in-curl-animation-also-on-click-of-the-button

Comment: @Naresh I posted link for sample code for page curl. I hope it'll help you. Please refer that example you will get your answer from that surely.

Comment: @mpp i want to use the curl animation on click of the button can i do this from that code ?