# Implement Page Curl/ Turn effect on single layout

Tags: android, curl, page-curl, page-flipping

I know page curl is discussed a lot times before(like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779862/how-can-we-show-page-curl-animation-on-click-of-the-button-in-android?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485204/page-curl-animation-issue/8485386#8485386)). Am supposed to do a book like application where while turning the pages would give the feel of a real book page. I have a layout which holds a text view and on next and previous button click am able to update the page content.

But implementing a pagecurl on this layout seems a lot difficult. Most of the samples do curl effect on images say 3 or 5 images. And some others do page curl effect on 2 layouts by flipping between them. In my case I need to bring this effect on my sublayout(linearlayout) within parent layout(relative). I just need to bring a curl effect on my sublayout so as to get the feel of book turning and content updation.

Does anyone have any idea.

Any suggestions/advise is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm facing a similar issure, what solution did you go with?